# Adding and removing JButtons in the code

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

So I am relatively new to Java and trying to create a checkers game using JButtons for the board and for the pieces. However I cannot seem to be able to remove a JButton via the ActionListener. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    checkersBeBitchin begin = new checkersBeBitchin();

}

public checkersBeBitchin(){
    box.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    makeBoard();
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setSize(600,600);
    setTitle("Checkers");


        }

private void makeBoard() {
    JPanel board = new JPanel();
    board.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<8; j++) {
            squares[i][j] = new JButton();
            ActionListener actionListener = new Board();
            squares[i][j].addActionListener(actionListener);
            if((i%2 != 0 && j%2 !=0) ||(i%2==0 && j%2 == 0) ){
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
                    pieceTracker[i][j]=0;
                    //System.out.println("Black"+i+","+j); debugging
                    if(i<3){
                        int blue = 1;
                        Icon piece = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/piece.png"));
                        JButton button = new JButton(piece);
                        //squares[i][j].setRolloverIcon("image dir") to make it prettier down the road.
                        squares[i][j].add(button);
                        pieceTracker[i][j]=blue;
                        ActionListener Listener = new Blue();
                        button.addActionListener(Listener);
                        }
                    else if (i>4){
                        int red=-1;
                        Icon piece = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/piece2.png"));
                        JButton button = new JButton(piece);

                        squares[i][j].add(button);
                        pieceTracker[i][j]=red;
                        ActionListener Listener = new Red();
                        button.addActionListener(Listener);
                        //squares[i][j].setRolloverSelectedIcon("/resources/piece2alt.png");
                        }

            }
            else{
                squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                pieceTracker[i][j]=0;
                //System.out.println("White"+i+","+j); //debugging
                }
            board.add(squares[i][j]);

            }

        }
    box.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
private class Blue implements ActionListener{


    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("You sexy Blue beast.");
        Object x = e.getSource();
        System.err.println(x);
        squares.remove(x);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

squares.remove? Should it read squares.remove(x)? Can we see the definition of squares? Is it an array? You must remove the button from the BOARD not the square, e.g. `board.remove(x)`

Comment: Yes sorry it is squares.remove(x); I was just messing around and forgot to put put it back to normal although that still does not work. This is how I initialized squares: JButton[][] squares = new JButton[8][8];

Comment: also board.remove expect an int but x is an object.

Comment: board is a JPanel and should provide also an remove(object) method! BTW: maybe you want to replace the button with a jlabel instead of really removing it?

Comment: trying board.remove(x) gives me an error: The method remove(int) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Object). Also I my plan was to remove a "piece" Jbutton and then create a new one at my next clicked location to play checkers.

Comment: the plan is not too bad, although for layout reasons you might want to replace the button with a label instead of removing it completely.

Comment: getSource() returns an object, try to cast it to `Component` before giving it to remove()

Comment: ok going to try and figure out how to cast it to a Component and I will let you know if that worked. Many Thanks

Comment: So I added these lines of code :
Component comp = (Component) x;
board.remove(comp);
the program now compiles but it does not remove the JButton from the board when it is clicked. I am sorry if I am making some very blatant error here.

Comment: I guess your "blatant error" is discussed here: http://www.javaneverdie.com/java/swing/how-to-remove-component-from-container/ Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks :) It seems it wont remove JButtons pieces but it will remove a JButton if I just have a JLabel on it. Just need to find a way to replace it with another JButton so that it works on my game.